# PopUp Variable Window not appearnig in Toad

Tags: toad

I using TOAD 9.7.2 with oracle10g database . Unexpectedly popup windows of variables is not appearing upon execution of code for passing parameters and showing empty results.
What could be the reason?

Regards

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: This is sample code                                                                                  SELECT * FROM MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS
WHERE INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the TOAD options: `View -> Toad Options...` and make sure that the `Prompt for substitution variables` is checked in the `Execute/Compile` section.

Comment: Thanks. It is  Ok now :)